# overloading operator for linear algebra

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I want to implement the Euler method in two dimensions and I don´t want to use any library (for practice).
Therefore I want to use my own linear algebra with overloaded functions. 
The two first overloads seem to work but there´s still a problem with the multiplication matrix * vector i.e a (2x2)*(2x1).

```
class vector{
    public:
        double a;
        double b;
        vector::vector();
        vector::vector(double a, double b){
            this->a = a;
            this->b = b;
        };
        vector operator+(vector &a);
        vector operator*(double factor);
        vector operator*(matrix &B);

    };

    class matrix{
    public:
        double a1;
        double a2;
        double b1;
        double b2;

        matrix::matrix();
        matrix::matrix(double a1, double a2, double b1, double b2) {
            this->a1 = a1;
            this->a2 = a2;
            this->b1 = b1;
            this->b2 = b2;

    };  
    };

    vector vector::operator+(vector& v){
        return vector(this->a+v.a,this->b+v.b);
    };

    vector vector::operator*(double factor){
        return vector(this->a*factor, this->b*factor);
    };

    vector vector::operator*(matrix& B){
        vector newv(this->a*B.a1 + B.a2*b, this->a*B.a1 + B.b2*b);
        return newv;
    };
```

Errors when I compile it:
'vector vector::operator *(matrix &)' : overloaded member function not found in 'vector'

unable to resolve function overload

Comment: And what is the problem you're having? Compiler errors? Runtime errors? Not behaving as you expect it to? Something else?

Comment: @picardlindekutta do you want to do matrix*vector ? and you are getting error there? if so define operator*() in matrix

Comment: I note that you defined the product `vector*matrix`. I suspect you wanted to define `matrix*vector`.

Comment: yeah sorry. very stupid not to mention the problem ...

Comment: i´ve got errors when i compile the code:
Error 6 error C3867: 'vector::b': function call missing argument list; use '&vector::b' to create a pointer to member \ode3\quelle.cpp 58 1 ODE3

Comment: @celtschk: you are right. but my problem is that i want to get a vector after the multiplication. is still possible if i define it as a operator in matrix?
also i think the direction doesn´t really matter for the errors?

Comment: @picardlindekutta: The return type is completely independent of where the function is implemented (except, of course, the type has to be known at the point of declaration; since you define `matrix` after `vector` this is already fulfilled inside `matrix`). Note that you also can define the operator as free function, outside of any class.

Comment: Where do you get the error? (And please, such information should be in the *question*.) Please edit your question to point out where in the posted source the error is. And if possible, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @celtschk: could you show me how to write it correct. I was looking up my whole book (which is "best book"...) but i could not find an error.
what seems to me as the big problem is the overload of the operator ' * '. Because I use it as factor * vector and vector * matrix (better: matrix * vector).

Would it be possible to declare in matrix something like: vector matrix::operator(vector &v) ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're a bit short on details, I must fill in the gap with guesses. My guess is that you try to support something like the following:

```
matrix m;
vector v, w;
// fill m and v with values
w = m*v;
```

I'm also guessing that your matrix has the following form:

```
( a1 a2 )
( b1 b2 )
```

You now have two options: Either implement matrix-vector multiplication in the class `matrix`, or implement it as a free function.

If you want to put if in the `matrix` class, you'd change the code as follows (note that there are many more things for the code that *should* be changed, but those are unrelated to the question):

```
class vector
{
  // omit the operator* for matrix, otherwise unchanged
};

class matrix
{
  // all that's already in the class

  vector operator*(vector const& v) const;
};

vector matrix::operator*(vector const& v) const
{
  return vector(a1*v.a + a2*v.b, b1*v.a + b2*v.b);
}

// the rest of your code
```

If you want to make it a free function (I personally would do it that way, but I'm sure that opinion is not universally held), you'd write

```
class vector
{
  // omit the operator* for matrix, otherwise unchanged
};

class matrix
{
  // completely unchanged
};

vector operator*(matrix const& m, vector const& v)
{
  return vector(m.a1*v.a + m.a2*v.b, m.b1*v.a + m.b2*v.b);
}

// the rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you, the first way was all I looking for!! But do you know why there´s an error in my solution? mustn´t i use this-->?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `this->` (in your constructors you even need it because your variables are shadowed by parameters). Where exactly the compiler generates the error is hard to say because the information you give is incomplete. For example, either your posted code is incomplete, or your error message, because as is, the compiler should have complained about the undeclared identifier `matrix` in your `operator*`.

Comment: I try to specify my problem the next time!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a [BLAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Linear_Algebra_Subprograms) library as an implementation in long term against reinvent the wheel again for basic matrix operations. Additionally some of the BLAS libraries are multithreaded and/or GPU based; they are widely used and tested.

In terms of design I would introduce functions what could be easily implemented by BLAS against operators:

```
C = α * A + β * B
C = α * A * B + β *C
```

So as a header:

```
...
bool blasAdd(const double alfa_, const Matrix& A_, const double beta_, const Matrix& B_, Matrix& C_);
bool blasMultiply(const double alfa_, const Matrix& A_, const Matrix& B_, const double beta_, Matrix& C_);
...
```

In this way your code automatically could be optimized for BLAS.

My favorite BLAS implementation is [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl), but there are also many free BLAS implementations in the market (e.g.: [boost BLAS](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl)).